# Need a help to get count by using query on mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How to a count of some product by grouping them and the names of products too using MVC?

The following query I made, but after that I don't know what to do.

```
var qrystr = new StringBuilder();
qrystr.Append("select SelectedPersonId, count(PersonName) as CountData from [dbo].[EntryMaster] Group by SelectedPersonId");
```

I need to show the `SelectedPersonId`, and the `CountData`...
How can I solve this through MVC?

Comment: if you're using EF code-first, why do you need to run queries like these?

Comment: @Adiga is absolutely right. You are loosing the whole point of EF

Answer (score 2):

If you're using entity framework, you can use `linq` to query your data set:

```
context.EntryMaster
     .GroupBy(e => e.SelectedPersonId)
     .Select(g => new { SelectedPersonId = g.Key, CountData = g.Count() })
     .ToList()
```

This returns a `List` of objects with 2 properties: `SelectedPersonId` and `CountData`

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just add .Count() at the end of the `qrystr.Append()`?